# Dynamically projecting with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, projection

## Given

(1) A database table, stored as a list of lists. The size of the table in terms of rows and columns is undefined.

```
List<List<string>> table = new List<List<string>>();
```

For example:

```
table.Add(new List<string>() { "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1" });
table.Add(new List<string>() { "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2" });
table.Add(new List<string>() { "a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3" });
```

```
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | e1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | e2 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | e3 |
```

(2) A list of integers. These integers resemble the indexes of database columns (zero-based), e.g.:

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4 };
```

## Problem

My aim is to project those columns from `table` of which the indexes occur in the list `indexes`. Given the above examples, the result should be:

```
| b1 | d1 | e1 |
| b2 | d2 | e2 |
| b3 | d3 | e3 |
```

## Current Solution

The best I could come up with is to iterate over all rows, like this:

```
List<List<string>> subtable = new List<List<string>>();
for (int index = 0; index < table.Count; index++)
{
    subtable.Add(table[index].Where((t, i) => indexes.Contains(i)).ToList());
}
```

## Request

A more elegant solution, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
List<List<string>> subtable =
    table.Select(row => indexes.Select(i => row[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

In case you need to check the array bounds, you can do this:

```
List<List<string>> subtable =
    table.Select(row => indexes.Where(i => i >= 0 && i < row.Count)
                               .Select(i => row[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
List<List<string>> subtable =
    (from row in table
     select
     (from i in indexes
      where i >= 0 && i < row.Count
      select row[i]
     ).ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Select all the rows, then for each row filter out the columns that are not in your index list:

```
var subtable = table
     .Select(row => row.Where((value, colIndex) => indexes.Contains(colIndex)))
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to print, it is simpler (and more efficient ) to do it without queries like this:

```
        List<List<string>> table = new List<List<string>>();
        table.Add(new List<string>() { "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1" });
        table.Add(new List<string>() { "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2" });
        table.Add(new List<string>() { "a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3" });

        List<int> indexes = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4 };

        for (int index = 0; index < table.Count; index++)
        {
            foreach (var columnIndex in indexes)
                Console.Write(table[index][columnIndex] +" ");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```